# I need help trying to create the frontend interface of a gui via tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The buttons, for some reason, seem to be positioned wrong. I checked my code, and it's written to have the correct positioning, but it for some reason is showing all of the buttons except for the "View All" buttons to be too low. The buttons are supposed to be right above each other. Could ya'll help and let me know what the problem is?

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()


#Labels

l1 = Label(window, text="Title")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

l2 = Label(window, text="Author")
l2.grid(row=0, column=2)

l3 = Label(window, text="Year")
l3.grid(row=1, column=0)

l4 = Label(window, text="ISBN")
l4 .grid(row=1, column=2)

#Entry boxes

title_text=StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=title_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

author_text=StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=author_text)
e2.grid(row=0, column=3)

year_text=StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=year_text)
e3.grid(row=1, column=1)

isbn_text=StringVar()
e4 = Entry(window, textvariable=isbn_text)
e4.grid(row=1, column=3)

#listbox

ls1 = Listbox(window, height=6,width=35)
ls1.grid(row=2, column=0)

#Scrollbar

scr1 = Scrollbar(window)
scr1.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=6)

#Making the scrolbar scroll down the listbox

ls1.configure(yscrollcommand=scr1.set)
scr1.configure(command=ls1.yview)

#Buttons and stuff

b1 = Button(window, text="View all", width=12)
b1.grid(row=2, column=3)
 
b2 = Button(window, text="Search Entry", width=12)
b2.grid(row=3, column=3)

b3 = Button(window, text="Add Entry", width=12)
b3.grid(row=4, column=3)

b4 = Button(window, text="Update Selected", width=12)
b4.grid(row=5, column=3)

b5 = Button(window, text="Delete Selected", width=12)
b5.grid(row=6, column=3)

b6 = Button(window, text="Exit", width=12)
b6.grid(row=7, column=3)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your Listbox is pretty tall, but occupies a single cell of the grid (since you gave it no `rowspan=` option).  Everything in a higher row number will therefore necessarily be entirely below the Listbox.  You probably want to give it the same rowspan as the Scrollbar.

Comment: Im not sure what u want, but here is my guess.  first one is to make `b1.grid(row=2, column=3,sticky=S)` this is because ur listbox is taking the space up in the same row as your button and the button is in middle of the listbox, so u can position is south of the grid cell

Comment: @jasonharper The row span and column-span thing for the listbox worked. Thanks!